# How to show random questions in android quiz

Tags: android

I am making a android quiz app I wanna show a random questions. It has different levels easy medium and Hard  But here when Question 1 appear the answers given is from Question 2.

Any help would be great thanks

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QUIZ";
private static final String TABLE_QUIZ = "quiz";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta";
private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb";
private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc";
private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd";
private static final String q_level = "level";
private static final String QuestionNumber = "q_number";
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
public String question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, answer;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase = db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD  +" TEXT, " + q_level + " TEXT, " + QuestionNumber + " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','1')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q2','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','2')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q3','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','3')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q4','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','4')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q5','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','5')");



    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','1')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','2')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','3')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','4')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','5')");


    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','1')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','2')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','3')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','4')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
            "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','5')");
    addQuestions();
    //db.close();
}

private void addQuestions() {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ);
    onCreate(db);
}



public void getQuestByLevel(String level, int qnum) {
   String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ +  " WHERE "+ q_level +"  = '"+ level +"' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;";


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            question=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUES));
            optionA=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTA));
            optionB=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTB));
            optionC=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTC));
            optionD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTD));
            answer=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER));


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specify?

Comment: @onurtaskin Here when i start the quiz I get the random question. Example I got the Question 1 but the answers I get is from Question 2

Answer (score 0):

you have to use random number generator to get random question from database table. here I will show you how get random question from database.

you have to manage different three level your own way or what ever your app logic here i ll explain hoe get random questions.

---

***Note: this is just logically answer you have to manage this by own way.***

first get all question id in integer array we can say it `itemQuestionID`

now create random number generate method like below way

```
public static int getRandom(int[] array) {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
    return array[rnd];
}
```

---

call that method

```
int queID = getRandom(itemQuestionID);
```

whatever question id you get show that question on screen.

---

**getRandom** method give you same question is one or more time to manage this in all question you have to handle which are already answered by user(by adding one more column in table or saving question id at some array)

***hope you understand this and do apropiate changes in your code***